# n-th Derivative

Tags: calculus, summation, binomial-coefficients, fractional-calculus

It can be proven the for a function $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$, letting $f^{(k)}(x)=\frac{d^k}{dx^k}f(x)$ and $g^{(k)}(x)=\frac{d^k}{dx^k}g(x)$ then the n-th derivative, for n is an integer is:
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)g(x)=\sum^n_{k=0}\left(\begin{align*}n\\k\\\end{align*}\right)f^{(n-k)}g^{(k)}(x)$$
Interestingly assuming a form similar to a binomial expansion. According to this result, my question is can this formula be extended to $\{n\in R\}$ where $R$ is the set of real numbers? It seems to be tricky as the $\sum^n_{k=0}$ operator doesn't exactly accept non integer values for $n$. However we know that there definitely exist formulas for $f^{(k)}$, $\{k\in R\}$ where $f$ is a certain function...thanks everyone

Comment: However we know that there definitely exist formulas for $f(k), {k∈\mathbb{R}}$, really?! But if it is so usually sums are substituted by integrals with some measures and binomial coefficients substituted by some analytic functions with the same properties.

Comment: Well yes...but not $f(k)$, but rather $f^{(k)}$. As in if $f(x)=x^n$, then $\frac{d^k}{dx^k}x^n=\frac{k!}{(k-n)!}\cdot x^{(k-n)}$ and extending $a!=\Gamma(a+1)$, we create a "fractional" derivative...

Comment: Or $\frac{d^k}{dx^k}\sin(x)=\sin\left(x+\frac{k\pi}{2}\right)$

Comment: Take a look at this article [A Further Extension of Leibnize Rule](http://www.rowan.edu/open/depts/math/osler/A%20Further%20Extension%20of%20Leibnize%20Rule.pdf)

Comment: @alexjo, Out of curiosity, can we extend this also to "fractional binomial expansions"? I mean, if $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)g(x)=\sum^n_{k=0}\left(\begin{align*}n\\k\\\end{align*}\right)f^{(n-k)}g^{(k)}(x)$, and it assumes a similar structure to a binomial expansion, then if there exist expressions for real numbers of n... can we, therefore develop expansions for $(x-y)^n$ where n is a real number?

Comment: @KeithAfas For $x,y,a\in\mathbb C$ $$(x+y)^a=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a^k\cdot\log^{k}(x+y)}{k!}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Notation**

In here the following notation is used:

$$\lfloor a\rfloor=\text{The largest integer smaller or equal to }a$$
$$[a]=a-\lfloor a\rfloor$$
$\Gamma(x)$ is the [gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

---

The general formula for the fractional derivative of $f(x)$ is

$$\frac{d^\alpha}{dx^\alpha}f(x)=\frac1{\Gamma(1-\alpha)}\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x \frac{f(t)}{(x-t)^\alpha}\mathrm dt$$

where $0 < \alpha < 1$

So if we wish to define

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)g(x)$$

with $n\in\mathbb R$, we simply combine the rule above and the rule that for $n\in\mathbb N$

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)g(x)=\sum^n_{k=0}\binom nkf^{(n-k)}g^{(k)}(x)$$

Here's what we do:

We know that

$$\frac {d^{[n]}}{dx^{[n]}}\frac {d^{\lfloor n\rfloor}}{dx^{\lfloor n\rfloor}}f(x)=\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)$$

So therefore
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)g(x)=\frac {d^{[n]}}{dx^{[n]}}\left(\sum^n_{k=0}\binom nkf^{(n-k)}g^{(k)}(x)\right)$$
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)g(x)=\frac1{\Gamma(1-[n])}\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x \dfrac{\displaystyle\sum^{\lfloor n\rfloor}_{k=0}\binom {\lfloor n\rfloor}kf^{(\lfloor n\rfloor-k)}g^{(k)}(t)}{(x-t)^{[n]}}\mathrm dt$$

Answer (score 1):

In such cases there are inequalities, instead of identities, controlling various Sobolev norms of $(fg)^{(n)}$ by the corresponding norms of $f^{(n)}$ and $g$ plus the ones of $g^{(n)}$ and $f$, i.e.,
$$
\|D^a(fg)\|\le c\big(\|D^af\|\|g\|+\|f\|\|D^ag\|\big),
$$
for some $C>0$ depending only on $a$ and the norm.

These are the Kato-Ponce inequalities.

See for examples [here.](http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.5144)